# Swift 3 xcode 8 firebase database error when update data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Morning everyone, I'm using Firebase and upgrade to the new version of Xcode I encountered a problem sending more data to the Firebase database.
Here is the error:

> Terminating app two to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue :) Can not store object of type _SwiftValue at SenderId. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray. '

I understand what is the problem and I also searched on the internet, the data I'm uploading are strings, after upgrading to Xcode gives me this error, does anyone have the same problem?

Should wait for a few days, I have also tried to update Firebase but there is no update for the library.

Comment: Give your code Where you face that error

Comment: Which Swift version are you using? Maybe you have to set the legacy value for Swift 2.3? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490507/how-can-i-use-swift-2-3-on-xcode8

Comment: swift 3, that's my code: override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
        
        let newMessageRef = messageRef.child(roomId).childByAutoId()
        let mes = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "MediaType": "text"]
        newMessageRef.setValue(mes)
        
        self.finishSendingMessage()
        
    }

Comment: i'm using jsqmessageviewcontroller

Answer (score 3):

It worked on JSQMessage too!!!

```
var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")

let newMessage = messageRef.childByAutoId()
let messageData: Dictionary<String, Any>? = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "mediaType": "TEXT"]
newMessage.setValue(messageData)
```

Comment: I resolved the problem using String as! NSString in my upload to Firebase Database, in DidPressSend Button

Answer (score 1):

i have been working on the same JSQMessage library ,, change your button code to this ,, i got it fixed ,, let me know how it goes

```
var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")


override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text:   String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    let newMessage = messageRef.childByAutoId()

    let messageData: Dictionary<String, Any>? = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "mediaType": "TEXT"]

     newMessage.setValue(messageData)

}
```

i added the Dictionary< String, Any>? on the second line of code inside my button action to fix the issue

Comment: I resolved the problem using String as! NSString in my upload to Firebase Database, in DidPressSend Button

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
this is how I fixed it:

my code that had an error:

```
    var videoInfoDic: Dictionary<String, Any?>?
```

how i fixed:

```
    var videoInfoDic: Dictionary<String, Any>?
```

took away the optional part. credit to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486888/5792500

Comment: I resolved the problem using String as! NSString in my upload to Firebase Database, in DidPressSend Button