# How can I use Swift 2.2 on Xcode8?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, xcode8

I had a project on `Swift2.3` and `XCode7`. It worked well.

When I have updated it to `XCode8` and `Swift3` the project does not show anything on the emulator so I decided to use, at least by the moment, `Swift2.2` on `Xcode8` (I have a copy of the project in `Swift2.2`) but it gives to me the following error:

> “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

I have tried going to `Build Settings > Use Legacy Swift Language Version` and change the default value from `Unspecified` to `No` but the error still comes.

Further, I only have three possible values to choose: `Yes`, `No` or `Unspecified` but none of them work to fix the error. Nothing about `SWIFT_VERSION` value.

How can I continue using `Swift2.2` on `XCode8` without any error?

**EDIT:** Here you have an image about the options that I actually have:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I know about this question [Use Swift 2.2 in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835397/use-swift-2-2-in-xcode-8) but as you can see on the image above I do not have the option `SWIFT_VERSION` so the only answer that appears there does not work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to set the Swift version for each target - also for Frameworks in Pods, if you use CocoaPods

Comment: You were using Swift 2.2 with Xcode 7, not 2.3.

Comment: @DejanSkledar Where can I set it?

Comment: in the Build Settings

Comment: @DejanSkledar I do not know if you refer to 'iOS Deployment Target' but there I have iOS 9.3 version to target it (the latest I had on my last project). I cannot see anymore option about versions.

Comment: @JAL I am so new to Swift and I was using the latest version but maybe I was wrong and I was using 2.2 (as I could see that in XCode8 they implement 2.3, correct me please if I am wrong). Also, it does not matter if I have my project on 2.2 or whatever. If I use the command `swift -version` on the project folder it says to me that it is on 3.0.

Comment: @Error404, Did you solved this issue?

Comment: @SunilTarge No, I had to rewrite my project on Swift3 because I was not able to make it work as before because all constraints broke and anything was shown on the simulator. I think there should be a better way to do that without have to rewrite the full project because it is like try to kill a fly with a gun.

Comment: @Error404, Thanks for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the value `2.3` in there.

http://imgur.com/a/pcLIJ

Comment: What do you mean when you say "there"?

Comment: In `Build Settings > Use Legacy Swift Language Version` for your target or the project itself.

Comment: There I have `Debug` and `Release` options. But any of them let me to choose 2.3 version. I think I am missing something because all of your refer to the same option and I cannot see anything related in that option.

Comment: I have edited my question with an image of the options that I have. I cannot set 3.0 where you have set it.

Comment: Could you remove the multiple values for debug and release? I guess you won't use different values for each deployment anyway.

Comment: I have removed them but I still have the three options. I will update my image now.

Comment: I double checked with other projects in Xcode 8 but in Swift projects I can enter any value. Maybe try to create a new project with Xcode 8 and move everything over there. Alternatively edit the project file by hand (but backup before).